# Firebase listen() on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-admin

I am creating a serverless infrastructure with multiple functions. So far I have managed to publish a new function on AWS lambda using the `aws-sam-cli`.

One of the last functions is my firebase listener which is supposed to trigger certain aws lambda functions.

Intially, I thought to create a new function and add the listener as follows:

```
import firebase_admin    
cred   = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(cert_json)
app    = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, config)
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

node_to_listen = '/alerts/'
firebase_admin.db.reference(node_to_listen).listen(listener)
```

However, the issue is that AWS lambda seems to be designed not to run functions continuously but only be triggered by events. This is true as well for the Firebase listen() function, which means that we get a chicken or egg problem, who triggers who?

How can I therefore publish the firebase listener function and where? Should it be deployed somewhere else (e.g. Heroku?) in order to continuously listen and send the event requests to aws lambda? Or is there a way to connect those two?

Comment: You can create a [CloudWatch event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) to trigger listener Lambda on a schedule like every minute or so. And all other Lambdas that listener is supposed to trigger can be subscribed to an AWS SNS topic. So listener will publish message to SNS topic and then topic will trigger all the subscribed Lambdas.

Comment: Yeah but the point is that the Firebase listener constantly listens to event and then instantaneously triggers the write operation as defined in the function listener(event). This sounds more like a cron job where you execute a function every minute or so. If a change happens on Firebase within that minute, it will not trigger the right response. We need to trigger the action when Firebase has identified a change.

Comment: So the function responsible for firebase change cannot publish the change event?

Comment: Yes it can publish a change event, but it needs to be running somewhere. If it runs on AWS lambda, then it wont run continuously.

Comment: It makes sense for a listener to run continuously but for the function that makes the change can publish the event realtime in SNS to invoke the downstream functions? sorry if i misunderstood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to keep an active listener in any Functions-as-a-Service environment that I know of. The whole purpose of such environments is to run (short) workloads in response to events. You are trying to actually to trigger an event by keeping a listener, which simply doesn't fit the FaaS model.

The two solutions I can see:

1. Implement your listener on an environment that keeps an active process.
2. Implement your listener on a FaaS environment that can itself listen to Firebase Realtime Database events. The only environment that can current do so it [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which has [Firebase Realtime Database as an event source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). So you'd then trigger your Lambda function from Cloud Functions.

The second solution is the only one that really feels fully serverless, but it seems a bit weird to trigger Amazon Lambda from Google Cloud Functions.

There is work under way to allow interop between FaaS providers. But I'm not sure of the current status (link to spec/working group welcome), nor if your scenario would be covered in there.

**Update**: also see  [Firebase listen() on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127524/firebase-listen-on-aws-lambda), now what GCP supports Eventarc.

Comment: I understand. But if there is something comparable as AWS Lambda for Cloud functions, then that would be the solution? Also, what is the typical use case of the firebase listener, is it usually number 1?

Comment: Lambda and GCF are both FaaS environments. What are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: The idea is to have a background process that creates summaries of certain reports/meta data. When a new report is added to Firebase, the function loads in all the reports of that day and creates a summary with the new updates values. Then it stores the aggregated values again on FB on a different node such that in the dashboard we do not have to do this process.

Comment: Honestly, I have just reviewed GCF from Firebase and this is exactly what I need. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases Compared to the Docs of Amazon Lambda, Firebase/Google Cloud (not sure the difference lately) is the preferred way to go. So much more user friendlier and deploying seems much more simple. Not to be biased or anything, but who wants to use Lambda when they have GCF? Just spent two days trying to understand Amazon docs.

Comment: Again I have to thank you very much for pointing out how Firebase enables to do what I intended to do. You guys are fantastic, I managed to program exactly what I wanted within 30 minutes without prior knowledge of Cloud Functions. Do you want me to update your question or add a separate answer to showcase how it works?

Comment: Thanks for the compliments John. It sounds like you should probably write a separate answer for your solution.