# Can we create firebase firestore triggers in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-firestore, aws-lambda

We are using firebase firestore as our database then some changes we want to write in lambda. As I already review the firebase documentation it is possible with firebase functions can we do it in lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support to have events in Firestore trigger a function in AWS Lambda.

Triggers from inside Google Cloud Platform are (nowadays) implemented with the open [Eventarc standard](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/overview), but the only [supported destinations](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/overview#targets) at the moment are Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, GKE, and Workflows, all inside Google Cloud Platform.

If you want to run the operation on AWS Lambda, you'd have to first implement a destination in one of these destination on GCP, and then call out to your Lambda function from there (and await the result to pass that back to GCP where applicable).

Also see:

- [Firebase listen() on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127524/firebase-listen-on-aws-lambda), from before GCP supported Eventarc